# $setEquals with list of lists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[The $setEquals aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) allows to compare two lists as sets for equality.

Let's say i have a list of lists like this:

```
lol = [['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

And a document structure like this in my db:

```
{
    "_id": "8...",
    "letters": [ 'b', 'a']
}
```

In the match stage of the aggregation i would like to get all documents where 
the set of "letters" equals **any** of the sets of `lol`.

In this case, the example document would be returned since the set of [ 'b', 'a'] equals the set of ['a', 'b'].

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to use `$setIsSubset` instead... Something like this `db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: {
    available: {
      $setIsSubset: [
        [{ $reverseArray: "$letters" }],
        lol
      ]
    }
  }}
])`

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there's no single operator for this. You could, however, either use `$or` to check each of them and build out that set of conditions programmatically, or you could add pipeline stages to your aggregation to 1. add the array of arrays as a field to each document, 2. `$unwind` the array, and finally 3. compare the individual unwinded array elements (i.e. each individual set) against your `letters` field.

Whichever approach you choose to take will largely depend on your memory limitations. If you're good on memory, I highly recommend the second option of the additional pipeline stages, otherwise you may want to consider stuffing the programmatically constructed `$or` operation into an existing pipeline stage.